# narrowing type of a vinyl record based on the lens/index chosen

Tags: haskell

Extensible records provided by http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vinyl are different from what other libraries
(HList and probably others like grapefruit-records/records) provide. This is because the result of the lookup is based on the pair `(result type, label)`, while the other libraries have the lookup based on `label` only. An example of this happening for vinyl:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, TypeOperators #-}
import Data.Vinyl
r = fixRecord $ (Field :: "x" ::: a) =: (3::Double)
        <+> (Field :: "x" ::: a) =: (2::Int)
main = do
    print $ rGet (Field :: "x" ::: Int) r
    print $ rGet (Field :: "x" ::: Double) r
-- prints 2\n3
```

For my application http://hackage.haskell.org/package/Rlang-QQ, the type
of the elements of the record will be determined by their usage later on,
so it seems I need the "x" to uniquely determine the value that's
stored there.

I want to avoid "redundant" type signature in the expression

```
(rGet (Field :: "z" ::: [Double])
    (ans :: PlainRec ("z" ::: [Double] ': '[])))
```

and have it look more like:

```
(rGet (Field :: "z" ::: [Double]) ans)
```

The whole code is in http://code.haskell.org/~aavogt/Rlang-QQ/examples/test2.hs
Is there some way to achieve this using vinyl, or should I adapt my code to
use another library?

Answer (score 1):

Vinyl will probably be [changed](https://github.com/jonsterling/Vinyl/issues/19#issuecomment-24280850) to have lookups based on the label only. In the meantime I had changed Rlang-QQ to use HList.